# Проблема с выводом текста через echo в PHP

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы текст, который проходил через `echo`, например `<p>Text</p>`, вывелся как `<p>Text</p>`, а не `Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[htmlspecialchars()](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

```php
echo htmlspecialchars('<p>Text</p>');
```